# Django form.is_valid() doesnt let anything go through. (False)

Tags: django

The program doesnt have any typos.

when i try to write to the database via forms and press submit, the request will come back, but wont be inserted into database.

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm

# Create your views here.

def homepage_welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage.html')

def addbook(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'bookadded.html')
        return render(request, 'addbook.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'addbook.html')

def borrowbook(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'borrowbook.html', {'booklist': books})

def book(request, pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'book':book}
    return render(request, 'book.html', context)

def bookadded(request):
    return render(request, 'bookadded.html')
```

```
# forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Book

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage_welcome),
    path('addbook/', views.addbook, name='addbook'),
    path('borrowbook/', views.borrowbook),
    path('book/<str:pk>/', views.book, name = 'book'),
    path('bookadded/', views.bookadded),
]
```

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
    booktitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I tried running the code without the if form.is_valid(): line, but that resoulted in "ValueError at /homepage/addbook/".

then i tried to put print() on each point where it cloud fail to find where is the error

```
def addbook(request):
    print(1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        print(2)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'bookadded.html')
            print(3)
        return render(request, 'addbook.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'addbook.html')
        print(4)
```

i found the

```
if form.is_valid():
```

line not accepting anything. now even integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form isn't validating. There is some error happening. Could be that you're not supplying a required field. When you use the _*all_* selector for the set of form fields, all fields are added to the form. Unless you specify otherwise all fields are required. My guess is that you are not supplying a date_created value because that's being handled in the backend. That's causing the form to fail.

Adding

```
print(form.errors)
```

after

```
form.is_valid()
```

will show you what those errors are.

Look at this issue: [how to display form.errors message properly in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187339/how-to-display-form-errors-message-properly-in-django)

It shows how to display form errors on the page. This will be helpful for both you and any potential users.